# Importing AngularJS directive into Angular 2+ component doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, angularjs-directive

I am working on an application that uses both AngularJS and Angular. I migrated one directive named `html-select.directive.ts` to Angular component. I am importing another directive in this directive i.e. `require('directives/angular-html-bind.directive.ts');`. But After migrating it to Angular component I am getting the following error on console.

```
angular.js:15697 Error: Template parse errors:
'angular-html-bind' is not a known element:
1. If 'angular-html-bind' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'angular-html-bind' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("ton" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <div class="oppia-dropdown-menu-text">
      [ERROR ->]<angular-html-bind class="oppia-html-select-selection-element" html-data="options[getSelectionIndex()"): ng:///SharedComponentsModule/HtmlSelectComponent.html@3:6
'angular-html-bind' is not a known element:
1. If 'angular-html-bind' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'angular-html-bind' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. (" choice of options" class="dropdown-item float-left">
      <a (click)="select(choice.id)">
        [ERROR ->]<angular-html-bind class="oppia-html-select-option protractor-test-html-multiple-select-option" html-"): ng:///SharedComponentsModule/HtmlSelectComponent.html@10:8
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2734)
    at TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:12704)
    at JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:28280)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:28268)
    at eval (compiler.js:28212)
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:28212)
    at eval (compiler.js:28125)
    at Object.then (compiler.js:2724)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:28124)
```

Before Migrating `html-select.directive.ts` looks like this.

```
require('directives/angular-html-bind.directive.ts');
require('domain/utilities/url-interpolation.service.ts');

// This directive allows user to put html into select's options.
// 'options' should be an array of objects containing attributes 'id' and 'val'
// Attribute 'val' is presented to the user. After user selection, the
// corresponding attribute 'id' is assigned to 'selection'.

angular.module('oppia').directive('htmlSelect', [
  'UrlInterpolationService', function(UrlInterpolationService) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        options: '=',
        selection: '='
      },
      templateUrl: UrlInterpolationService.getDirectiveTemplateUrl(
        '/components/forms/custom-forms-directives/html-select.directive.html'),
      controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.select = function(id) {
          $scope.selection = id;
        };

        $scope.getSelectionIndex = function() {
          for (var index = 0; index < $scope.options.length; index++) {
            if ($scope.options[index].id === $scope.selection) {
              return index;
            }
          }
        };
      }]
    };
  }
]);
```

After Migrating `html-select.directive.ts` to Angular Component, it becomes like this.

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { downgradeComponent } from '@angular/upgrade/static'

require('directives/angular-html-bind.directive.ts');

@Component({
  selector: 'html-select',
  templateUrl: './html-select.component.html',
  styleUrls: []
})

export class HtmlSelectComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() options: Array<any>;
  @Input() selection: any;

  constructor () {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {

  }

  select(id) {
    this.selection = id;
  }

  getSelectionIndex() {
    for (var index = 0; index < this.options.length; index++) {
      if (this.options[index].id === this.selection) {
        return index;
      }
    }
  }
}

angular.module('oppia').directive(
  'htmlSelect', downgradeComponent(
    {component: HtmlSelectComponent}));
```

The `html-select.component.html` file is this -

```
<div uib-dropdown class="oppia-html-select">
  <button uib-dropdown-toggle class="btn btn-secondary oppia-html-select-selection" type="button" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <div class="oppia-dropdown-menu-text">
      <angular-html-bind class="oppia-html-select-selection-element" html-data="options[getSelectionIndex()].val">
      </angular-html-bind>
    </div> 
  </button>
  <ul uib-dropdown-menu class="oppia-dropdown-menu">
    <li *ngFor="let choice of options" class="dropdown-item float-left">
      <a (click)="select(choice.id)">
        <angular-html-bind class="oppia-html-select-option protractor-test-html-multiple-select-option" html-data="choice.val">
        </angular-html-bind>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul> 
</div>
```

I am new to Angular, that's why I am not able to figure out why `require('directives/angular-html-bind.directive.ts');` is not working in Angular component. Any help is highly appreciated.